# How to I get text from a KivyMDTextField?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Hi I am trying to get text from a text field but it is not working here is my code.
Python:

```
class FileScreen(Screen):
    
    def pr(self):
        text = self.get_screen('login').ids.title.text
        print(text)
```

I am then trying to get text from this text field:

```
<FileScreen>:
    id:"file"
    name: "FileScreen"
    MDFloatingActionButton:
        id: "fbutton"
        icon: "checkbox-marked-circle-outline"
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .85, "center_y": .1}
        on_release: root.pr()
    MDTextField:
        id: "description"
        size_hint_x: .875
        size_hint_y: .65
        mode: "rectangle"
        multiline: True
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
    MDTextField:
        id: "title"
        size_hint_x: .7
        size_hint_y: .12
        hint_text: "Enter Title"
        font_size: 22
        max_text_length: 20
        required: True
        

        
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .4, "center_y": .075}
```

I don't know what is going on here hope someone can help.

### John Anderson error when using his answer:

```
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 861, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 KeyError: 'title'

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\Users\Gavin\Documents\last left python android app\main.py", line 88, in <module>
     app().run()
   File "C:\Users\Gavin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 950, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\Gavin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 582, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\Gavin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 347, in mainloop
     self.idle()
   File "C:\Users\Gavin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 391, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "C:\Users\Gavin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 342, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "C:\Users\Gavin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 308, in post_dispatch_input
     wid.dispatch('on_touch_up', me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Gavin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\button.py", line 1487, in on_touch_up
     super(MDFloatingActionButton, self).on_touch_up(touch)
   File "C:\Users\Gavin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\behaviors\ripple_behavior.py", line 296, in on_touch_up
     return super().on_touch_up(touch)
   File "C:\Users\Gavin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\button.py", line 981, in on_touch_up
     return super().on_touch_up(touch)
   File "C:\Users\Gavin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\button.py", line 1101, in on_touch_up
     return super().on_touch_up(touch)
   File "C:\Users\Gavin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 179, in on_touch_up
     self.dispatch('on_release')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 705, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1248, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1132, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Gavin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 57, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "C:\Users\Gavin\Documents\last left python android app\main.kv", line 51, in <module>
     on_release: root.pr()
   File "c:\Users\Gavin\Documents\last left python android app\main.py", line 24, in pr
     text = self.ids.title.text
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 864, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

Updated my code to your answer and now getting this error.
I don't know what the error means so maybe you do.

Answer (score 0):

The `get_screen()` method must use the `name` of the `Screen`, not the `id`. But the code in question is already in the `FileScreen` class, so you don't need the `get_screen()` call at all. Try changing that line to:

```
text = self.ids.title.text
```

Also, the `ids` that you provide in your `kv` should not be strings, for example:

```
MDTextField:
    id: "title"
```

should be:

```
MDTextField:
    id: title
```

Comment: added my error to the question when using the code you recommended.